# How would you use a proxy erc20 contract if you cannot preserve msg.sender?

Tags: delegatecall

Let's say I use a proxy contract which allows me to make an ERC20 token transfer from my account.

At the moment the only way to do so is to use tx.origin which gets the original EOA address of the caller but this is not stable and often not implemented in ERC20 contracts.

My question is, how to allow a proxy contract to make ERC20 transfers on behalf of the user even though msg.sender becomes the proxy contract's address? I am aware you could approve an allowance but this requires an extra transaction and I would like to do it in one.

Comment: Are you asking about how to design a contract to make this easy, or are you asking about how to build a proxy contract that can interact with existing ERC20 token contracts?

Comment: With existing contracts